# Solving a PDE from the Feymann-Kac formula

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let $u:[0,T]\times\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}_+$, $T>0$, $r>0$, $\mu>0$, $\sigma>0$ and $A>0$.

What is the solution to the following PDE:
\begin{equation}
u_t(t,x)+\mu x u_x(t,x)+\frac{\sigma^2x^2}{2}u_{xx}(t,x)-ru(t,x)+\frac{1}{A+x}=0
\end{equation}
with the terminal condition $u(T,x)=0$.

By Feymann-Kac theorem, $u$ has the probabilistic representation
$$u(t,x)=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_t^Te^{-r(u-t)}\frac{1}{A+S_u}du|S_t=x\right]$$
where $S$ follows the SDE
$$dS_t=\mu S_tdt+\sigma S_tdW_t.$$
However, to find $u$ by first solving $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{A+S_u}\right]$ does not lead to an analytical solution because the random variable $\frac{1}{A+S_u}$ follows a logit normal distribution which is known for not having analytical expression for the mean.

Comment: There is a $r$ in the first equation. Is that a typo? Should it be $t$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to declare $r>0$, now it is edited.

Comment: Function $1/(A+x)$ is not integrable. Is it proven that a solution exists?

Comment: Since $S_t>0$ a.s. for all $t\in[0,T]$, then $0<\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{A+S_u}]\leq \frac{1}{A}$, hence, it has finite moment. A solution $u$ should exist because the probabilistic representation is well-defined.

Comment: Based on a past question you asked, don't you rather mean $\frac{1}{A+\exp(\pm x)}$?
As it stands, note that $\mathbb{E}\big(\frac{1}{A+S_u}\big)$ does not exist, since the integral does not converge

Comment: $S_t$ is a function of normal random variable $N$ as the geometric Brownian motion $S=S_0\exp((\mu-\sigma^2/2)t+\sigma W_t)$, then one can just integrate $N$ over the density of normal distribution. Can you show why the integral does not converge?